What can be said about a semigroup $M$ from its topos $\mathit{Sets}^M$?
Please recommend some review "what can be said about a semigroup $M$ from its topos $\mathit{Sets}^M$". For example, for which semigroups are de Morgan's laws true?

Morgan Rogers "Toposes of Monoid Actions"
https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.10198
